# Firebase add 'g.Bg.Cg' to object key

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get key of channel and add this key to path. This is my code:

```
firebase.database().ref('channels/').orderByKey().limitToLast(1).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
            const channel =  Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0];
            createUserChannel(channel, currentUser, db);
....
function createUserChannel(channel, currentUser, db) {
            db.list('channelUsers/' + channel).push(currentUser);
        }
```

But I have this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Reference.push failed: 
first argument contains a function in property 'channelUsers.- 
LDCclTrWKekW0MqUy-n.g.Bg.Cg' with contents = function XMLHttpRequest() { 
[native code] }
```

I don't have 'g.Bg.Cg' in my channel key. What is this?

Comment: It's hard to say what precisely is going on, since we can't see the values of `channel`, `db,` and `currentUser`. Can you reproduce the problem with hardcoded values for each of those, and then update your question to show those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
    firebase.database().ref('channels/').orderByKey().limitToLast(1).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
       snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
         const channel = childSnapshot.key;
        // ...
       });

    //..............
```

Have a look at the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key

and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events), the documentation for Queries, where it says "Even when there is only a single match for the query, the snapshot is still a list; it just contains a single item. To access the item, you need to loop over the result:"

Comment: Sorry, this is my mistake. Since you do a query we need to loop over the children. I've updated.

Comment: Same error again. When I console.log channel I have right key, but when I do push I got same error :(

Comment: You should use set or update, see the specificity of push here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push

Comment: Yes, another problem was in push(). Now it works correctly, thank you!

Comment: Happy that I coud help you. You may accept the answer, by clicking the grey checkmark on the left of the answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer. Thanks and welcome to SO.